# Playwright script not fetching all the products due to page scroll

Tags: node.js, playwright

I am trying to scrape some data from a webpage using this script on playwright

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('Extract Mobile Product Names', async ({ page }) => {
  // Navigate to the target website
  await page.goto('https://mistore.pk/collections/redmi-phones');

  // Wait for the '.product-title' selector to be visible for all products
  await page.waitForSelector('.product-title');

  // Locate all anchor elements with the class 'product-title'
  const productTitleElements = await page.$$('.product-title');

  // Initialize a counter
  let productCount = 0;

  // Extract and print the text content of each product title element
  for (const element of productTitleElements) {
    const productName = await element.textContent();
    console.log(productName.trim()); // Trim to remove leading/trailing spaces
    productCount++; // Increment the counter
  }

  // Print the total number of products
  console.log(`Total products: ${productCount}`);
});
```

The script only logs 20 products on the console. The remaining 11 products won't load because of lazy loading(?) I think

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it could be happening because of lazy loading. If that is indeed the case, you can simulate scrolling on the page to trigger the lazy loading of the remaining content. You can try something like this,

```js
test('Extract Mobile Product Names', async ({ page }) => {
  //... Navigate to the target website
  // ... Wait for the '.product-title' selector to be visible for the initial products

  // Scroll to the bottom of the page to trigger lazy loading
  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      const maxScrollAttempts = 10 // You can adjust this value
      let scrollAttempt = 0

      const scrollInterval = setInterval(() => {
        window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight)
        scrollAttempt++

        if (scrollAttempt >= maxScrollAttempts) {
          clearInterval(scrollInterval)
          resolve()
        }
      }, 1000) // You can adjust the interval time if needed
    })
  })

  // Wait for the additional product titles to load
  await page.waitForSelector('.product-title', { state: 'attached' });

  // ... Locate all anchor elements with the class 'product-title'

  // ... Initialize a counter

  // ...Extract and print the text content of each product title element

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using images load state to verify overall page load state:

```
   // Trigger lazy loading of all elements *in parallel* to load faster by verifying the images
     const locators = await page.locator('.product-image');
     await locators.evaluateAll(e => e.scrollInfoView());
     const promises = locators.map(locator => locator.evaluate(image => image.complete || new Promise(f => image.onload = f)));
        // Wait for all in parallel
     await Promise.all(promises);

    //verifying expected item count
    await expect(locators).toHaveCount(expectedValue);
```